# if statement in excel, adding 1 if cell with text but

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, formula

I am creating an excel sheet that has three columns. Detail, month and month count

1 -- I would like for the formula to look at the detail column and if there is text add the previous cell number plus 1 to new month count, if not insert 0

2-- I would like the formula to add the previous cell before the cell with 0 and for the cell with 0 not to impact the other cells or reset the cells back to 1 witch is the problem am having

3-- I also need the formula to reset for every month from what ever number it was back to 0 or 1 depending if the new month first cell has text or not. for this I need the formula to look at the month column

This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(G95), I94+ 1, 0)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution or an excel formula?

Comment: `...add the previous cell number...` How is `I94` previous to `G95`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Assuming the formula is being entered in `I95`, he's checking column `G` for text and, if found, he wants the count from the cell above (`I94`) plus one.

Comment: @eudeirys - I think it may make more sense to just post a sample of your data and explain what you're trying to accomplish. There may be a better way to get what you want than by using the formula you're trying to write.

Comment: Thank you for your help but someone else has solved this problem for me . Again thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the count column should be as follows.

```
=IF(A2<>"",COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)-COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,"",$B$1:B2,B2),0)
```

Breakdown of how this works:

- `A2<>""` Will check if the detail column is populated
- `COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)` will figure out how many entries are above this row that reference the same month.
- `COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,"",$B$1:B2,B2)` Will find how many cells are blank provided that it also matches the month. This subtracted from the  previous section gives you how many are not blank.
- The `IF` will return 0 if the detail is empty.

Which returned the following data

```
Orderly             Random
Det Mon Count       Det Mon Count
X   1   1               2   0
X   1   2           X   1   1
X   1   3           X   1   2
    1   0               2   0
X   1   4           X   2   1
X   2   1           X   1   3
X   2   2           X   1   4
    2   0               1   0
    2   0               1   0
    2   0               2   0
    3   0               3   0
X   3   1           X   3   1
    3   0               1   0
X   3   2               3   0
X   3   3           X   1   5
    3   0           X   2   2
X   3   4           X   3   2
    3   0               3   0
X   3   5               3   0
X   3   6               2   0
```

Comment: Hey quick question, how would  I create a similar formula that does not reset every month and would give me a yearly count. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just update the references to column B to the year column. If you have your columns as `Detail | month | year | CountMonth | CountYear`, you would have `CountMonth` as described above, and for `Count`Year, you would change any reference to column B to C.

Comment: well I don't want the years to reset, I just want the formula to look at the detail column and to add one to the year column to get the yearly count and if it's zero not add 1 to the following cell. This is for one year count.

Comment: Well, assuming you only have one year in a given  column, you could just use `=COUNTA($A$1:A2)`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to keep a running total for the month count in the column and put a 0 if there is not text. If that is the case, you can put this formula in I95.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(G95),MAX($I$2:I94)+1, 0)
```

Comment: That won't reset for each month.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to set the value back to 1.  @Brian

Comment: Then how do you satisfy the third criteria that is asked for?

Comment: @BrianCohan Sorry, i didn't understand the 3rd criteria that way the first 10 times a read through it.